# Reversing order of elements in a priority Queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am pushing stuff into a priority Queue and I've made a comparison method for elements that go in there ,  when I checked the order , I realized I wanted elements to go in the other way around , so I went and changed all the boolean returns from my comparison method to be opposite of what they originally were and now it gives me a million assertion failures. If I ignore them , the program still works as expected , but why the assert fails ? Why should the program care ?

```
 bool operator()(charElement &operand1,charElement &operand2)
{
    // If the frequency of op1 < op2 then return true
    if(operand1.i_frequency < operand2.i_frequency) return true; //change to false

    // If the frequency of op1 > op2 then return false
    if(operand1.i_frequency > operand2.i_frequency)return false; //change to true

    // If the frequency of op1 == op2 then return true (that is priority is indicated to be less even though frequencies are equal)
    if(operand1.i_frequency == operand2.i_frequency)return true; //change to false

    // By default , return true (that is priority is indicated to be less)
    return true; //change to false
}
```

**By the way, why was my query downvoted ? I try to ask sane questions and I believe this is one of them.**

Specifics : I changed the operator definition to what @sehe suggested. Now if I add a not operator to the return value, it gives me assertion failures (invalid operator<) inside the include file  , line number 2457. I checked the file , it seems that the error is in an inline method called Push_heap_0 , but I am stumped as to what that code does

Comment: where do you get failed asserts?

Comment: Since you didn't give any details whatsoever about the assertions that's failing, we can't possibly help you.

Comment: @DeadMG , I have , they are in the comments , hold on I will edit the question to put them in.

Comment: "_By default , return true_" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you simply reverse the order of the parameters? That is, replace:

```
bool operator()(charElement &operand1,charElement &operand2)
```

with:

```
bool operator()(charElement &operand2,charElement &operand1)
```

Then you can leave the body of the function as it is.

On a side note, comparisons are read-only operations, and we should always respect const correctness:

```
bool operator()(const charElement& operand2, const charElement& operand1)
```

Also, you are not allowed to return `true` if the elements are equal:

```
if(operand1.i_frequency == operand2.i_frequency)return true;   // HUGE PROBLEM!
```

You must always return `false` in that case, no matter if you want "normal" or "backwards" order.

The opposite of `<` is *not* `>`, but `>=`. This seems to be hard for programmers to grasp.

Comment: "The opposite of < is not >, but >=. This seems to be hard for programmers to grasp." Makes it quite clear, but what I don't understand is , why does the system care. In this scenario , I can do without returning "true" , but say I wanted to , it will just define an operator which will assume something is less , even if its equal.

Comment: You cannot assume something is less, even if it's equal. That would break the invariant that either `a < b` or `b < a` *must* be false. You cannot invent your own semantics for `<`, it just doesn't work.

Comment: @angryInsomniac "_it will just define an operator which will assume something is less , even if its equal._" if it is equal, how could it be less?

Comment: @curiousguy In the same way as in the current scheme of things it assumes priority is greater , even if it is equal.

Comment: @angryInsomniac You understand that you need to start with a total order, don't you?

Comment: Is "total order" a term that I should know ?

Comment: Just to be clear: you should not invent your own semantics for `<` in c++. It is perfectly valid to do so, just like in normal math, but it will break basically everything that relies on it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be many things

- what is the type of charElement.i_frequency?
- how are you using the dequeue (type && constructor && algorithms invoked)

That said, it looks like you can greatly simplify your comparator.
My preferred idiom for this

```
bool operator()(charElement &operand1,charElement &operand2)
{
    return operand1.i_frequency < operand2.i_frequency;
}
```

or for reverse logic:

```
bool operator()(charElement &operand1,charElement &operand2)
{
    return operand1.i_frequency > operand2.i_frequency;
}
```

If it is actually a compound and a little more complex:

```
bool operator()(charElement &operand1,charElement &operand2)
{
    return std::tie(operand1.i_frequency, operand1.otherfield) < 
               std::tie(operand2.i_frequency, operand2.otherfield);
}
```

Comment: That's great and all , would compress the code , but I'll have to check if returning NOT of the operation still gives me the assertion errors.

Comment: @angryInsomniac: Yeah I just typed up some ideas (mainly, why we can't answer that without seeing more code/the assertions)

Comment: Will do , more info as soon as I get home :) (I thought it might be something obvious)

Comment: Specifics :
I changed the operator definition to what @sehe suggested.

Comment: Specifics :
I changed the operator definition to what @sehe suggested. Now if I add a not operator to the return value, it gives me assertion failures inside the include file <algorithm> , line number 2457. I checked the file , it seems that the error is in an inline method called Push_heap_0 , but I am stumped as to what that code does.

Comment: Why don't you show us (a) what container definition, (a) what algorithm? We cannot guess what your implementation of algorithm contains in line 2457. Adding the relevant info will certainly help stop the downvotes. Consider just providing a [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions/22762#22762)...?

Comment: Since you are seeing the problem only when reversing, it stands to reason that you are not passing consistent comparison predicates to containers and algorithms. It will be trivial to spot, but not when there is no code.